# Ways to display numbers in assembly language

Tags: assembly, pic18

In the following code below I am not sure what the `D'93'` and `D'122'` mean. The only time I have used assembly in the past hexadecimal numbers or binary numbers have been used. What does this notation mean and how can I convert into something I can understand so I can check the math by hand?

```
#include <p18F452.inc>
SUM     EQU 0x10
        ORG 0x00
        GOTO START
        ORG 0x20
START:  MOVLW D'93'
        MOVWF SUM
        MOVLW D'122'
        ADDWF SUM,W
        BNC SAVE
        SETF WREG
SAVE:   MOVWF SUM
        SLEEP
        END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `D` stands for decimal. By default unqualified numbers are interpreted as hexadecimal unless overridden by the `RADIX` or `LIST` directives.

Qualifiers/prefixes used by MPASM:

- `B'10'` for binary
- `O'10'` for octal
- `D'10'` for decimal (can also be written as `.10`)
- `H'10'` for hexadecimal (can also be written as `0x10`)
- `A'a'` for ASCII (can also be written as `'a'`)

Comment: So, D'93' = .93 and D'122' = .122?

Comment: Yes. By the way you might want to keep this [document handy](ftp://ftp.nottingham.ac.uk/pub/pic84/33014f.pdf).